# Hot Reload being triggered on Visual Studio 22 when no changes are made

Tags: visual-studio

I have a breakpoint in a loop. I begin debugging, then turn my keyboard off so no changes to the code can occur. I use my mouse to press the Continue button when I break on the breakpoint.

After a random amount of Continues, the Hot Reload dialog appears. Trying to press Edit and Continue causes the dialog to reappear. I can stop and restart the program with no changes.

Anyone else ever run into this?

Version 17.1.2

Comment: This is driving me up the wall. Did you ever find a solution or root cause? My breakpoint isn't even in a loop and it still says I have changes whenever I hit it.

Comment: Still an issue with 17.4.4. I closed and reopened the project and the issue no longer occurred.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305219/visual-studio-2022-debugger-thinks-i-changed-code-and-wants-to-hot-reload

Comment: See my answer here, hope it'll help you as it helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77728014/421891

Comment: Still having this issue with version 17.9.0 and my breakpoint is nowhere near any loop either.