# Visual Studio 2022 Debugger thinks I changed code and wants to hot reload

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

EDIT:  Good information provided below to diagnose, but the issue was I was running Visual Studio 2022 17.3.  Version 17.4 is required for .NET 7, and I had just installed that.  Once I installed the latest version of VS, all my problems went away.  [Install with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70#install-with-visual-studio)

Suddenly today, debugging my ASP.NET Core 6 and 7 apps suddenly has stopped working.  I hit F5 to debug, it stops on my breakpoint, but as soon as I continue or step into, I'm shown this dialog:[image]

I haven't made any changes to code, I'm simply trying to continue after I've stopped at a breakpoint.  This just started happening today and I can't figure out what I did.

Comment: In visual studio within `Tools > Options > Debugging > .NET/C++ Hot Reload` [`what configuration you can see here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAAsm.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with VS 17.5.5 and a simple .NET7 console application; XUnit is able to run the test.
I can start the test with debugger attached till a break point is reached, then I can't step over because of the Hot reload popup.

I fixed this issue by removing the PublishSingleFile attribute from the console csproj:

```
<!--<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>-->
```

It seems it will be fixed in .NET8
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42927

Answer (score 1):

Today this happened to me, I couldn't debug project, this popup appeared on every break point.

I fixed it by **removing folder** `.vs` located near your solution file.
This folder will be recreated when you open solution next time.